# ¿Cómo convertir un objeto a entero?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedure, ado.net

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
public void Crear(UsuarioDto registro) {
    VisitantesEntities db = new VisitantesEntities();
    registro.Id = Convert.ToInt32(db.SpUsuarioMaxId());
    db.SpCrearUsuario(registro.Id, registro.Nombre, registro.Correo, registro.CodigoAcceso, registro.ClaveAcceso, registro.UsuarioId, registro.RolId);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

En el recibo el objeto **registro** para almacenar sus valores en base de datos mediante el store procedure `SpCrearUsuario`. Sin embargo, antes debo encontrar el Id del último usuario, para lo cual uso el store procedure `SpUsuarioMaxId`, pero al tratar de convertir el resultado de este store procedure a `Int` para poder asignarle el valor a `registro.Id` me muestra el siguiente error:

```
System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult`1[System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]]' to type 'System.IConvertible'.'
```

¿Es posible convertir el resultado de un objeto en un entero?

El código del Store Procedure es este:

```
USE [Visitantes]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SpUsuarioMaxId]
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT MAX(Id) AS MaxId
    FROM Usuario
END;
```

Comment: Me parece que ahí tendrías que recibir la info que devuelve el sp en una ICollection<T> del modelo que devuelve el store o si no prueba recibirlo en una lista List<T>, y luego de eso tendrías que leer el objeto de la lista en la posición 0 .
List<T> a = (List<T>)(db.SpUsuarioMaxId()).. algo así

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para evitar el problema se utiliza `ISNULL`

```
SELECT ISNULL(MAX(Id), 0) AS MaxId FROM Usuario
```

pero recuerda que al id que obtienes debes sumar uno para generar el siguiente

Ademas recomedaria evalues si ese id no puedes definirlo como `IDENTITY` en la tabla de la db,o sea autonumerico, asi se incrementa automaticamente cuando realizar el insert

Comment: Agregaré el ISNULL para mejorar el código, sin embargo, ya verifiqué que el sp si devuelve un valor entero, el problema que tengo es al convertirlo a int para poder pasarlo al otro sp. Si debo sumarle 1 antes de pasarlo.

Answer (score 5):

Tal como menciona [@Japh Sxas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/158438/c%c3%b3mo-convertir-un-objeto-a-entero#comment297597_158438) en su comentario, el tipo `ObjectResult<T>` implementa `IEnumerable<T>`, por lo que es probable que tu procedimiento retorne más de un elemento, para obtener el valor que deseas *(Si sólo existirá un registro como producto de esa consulta)*, puedes hacer:

#### Método número 1:

Cambia esta linea:

```
registro.Id = Convert.ToInt32(db.SpUsuarioMaxId());
```

Por:

```
registro.Id = Convert.ToInt32(db.SpUsuarioMaxId().FirstOrDefault() ?? 1);
```

> Probablemente quieras hacer un chequeo de valor, porque si `SpUsuarioMaxId()` retorna `null` o `0`, es probable que no puedas agregar el elemento a la base de datos.

Para hacer uso de la función `FirstOrDefault()` debes hacer `using System.Linq;` al principio del archivo.

#### Método número 2 *(No probado)*:

Este método no lo he probado, pero debería funcionar. Cambia la definición de tu procedimiento almacenado por:

```
USE [Visitantes]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SpUsuarioMaxId]
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @MaxId int = (SELECT MAX(Id) FROM Usuario)
    RETURN @MaxId
END;
```

Con esa modificación, tu procedimiento almacenado debería poder retornar directamente el valor como entero, luego de realizar dicha modificación, debes actualizar tu modelo de Entity Framework para que el tipo de retorno cambie.

Saludos,

Comment: Efectivamente al utilizar registro.Id = Convert.ToInt32(db.SpUsuarioMaxId().FirstOrDefault() ?? 1); quedó resuelto el problema, seguidamente le sumo 1 y puedo utilizar este valor para el siguiente sp.

Answer (score 3):

Intenta modificando esto, parece que el valor retornado es `null`.

```
int? Id_sp = db.SpUsuarioMaxId();
registro.Id = Convert.ToInt32(((Id_sp == null) ? 1 : Id_sp));
```